# Using pythons open function for .png Image

Tags: python

Im getting an error when using pythons inbuild function "open" and don't know how to get it to work for png files.

**Examplecode**: `img =open('here.png').read()`

**Error**: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 101: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: What did you expect to happen?  The contents of a .png are not going to make any sense as a string.  You can read it as binary data via `open('here.png', 'rb')`, but there's not much you could do with that data without using an image manipulation library such as PIL/Pillow.

Comment: PNG files aren't text files, so you need to open them in binary mode. But what are you going to do with those bytes once you have them?

Comment: you are trying to open the "png" file like a text file. this won't work as they are different try using the open cv method shown this will store your image in the form of a 2d array or matrix if you want to be technical. don't forget to install opencv before you try it

Comment: @jasonharper I expected it to read the image in a binary format so that I can store it in a TFRecords file, 'rb' works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open images, i suggest you to use `opencv` or `PIL` module of python.
**Using OpenCV**:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('here.png',0)
```

**Using PIL**:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("here.png")
im.show()
```

**If you just want to open using `open` :**

```
img =open('here.png','rb').read()
```

Comment: That second argument is a flag . read the documentation at https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to send the image file through FTP you might need to open the file use this

```
file = open(file_location,'rb')
```

and then you can use this to send the file

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+file_location, file)
```

I use it a million times daily :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using imageio for python3 that calls the pillow package which is a branch of PIL.

```
 frame = imageio.imread('png here')
```

and to make sure the frame is not being converted to something else like uint16 => uint8, I make sure of the dtype

```
 print (frame.dtype)
```